# Centering the latex table in the page

Tags: latex, r-markdown, centering

I have the following table in `LaTeX`, and although I have used the `\centering` in the code, it is not centred when knitted. In addition it extends more than the text width as shown in the figure below

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption[mnodels summary]{Summary results of the models \label{tab:modelssummary}}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{~ \textbf{~~Models Performance }}                                                                                        \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Model}   & \textbf{Residual Mean} & \textbf{Constant Variance} & \textbf{Autocorrelation} & \textbf{Adj. R-Squared} & \textbf{AIC}  \\ 
\hline\hline
\textbf{Model 1} & OK                     & OK                         & YES                      & 0.83                    & 4804.8        \\
\textbf{Model 2} & OK                     & OK                         & YES                      & 0.84    & 4569.5        \\
\textbf{Model 3} & OK                     & OK                         & YES                      & 0.83                    & 4763.7        \\
\textbf{Model 4} & OK                     & OK                         & YES                      & 0.87                    & 3760.5        \\
\textbf{Model 5} & OK                     & OK                         & YES                      & 0.86                    & 3964.5        \\
\textbf{Model 6} & No                     & No                         & YES                      & 0.32                    & 10879.7~      \\
\textbf{Model 7} & No                     & No                         & YES                      & 0.80                    & 5434.2        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and it will look like this:
[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You're table will automatically be centred if you use shorter words in your header row and/or split them over two lines

Comment: Yes. this worked pretty well. but can I make the fonts of only this table a little it smaller so that there will be no need to make the words shorter?

Comment: Don't mix too many font sizes in your document, this will look like a ransom letter

Answer (score 1):

If you accept multi lines in headings and abbreviations, you can squeeze the table and even fit within the default latex page. Then, `\centering` will work

[image]

and the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
  \captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=6pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % Centering
\usepackage{siunitx}    % S[...]

% Makecell - settings
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{tc}

% Custom column types
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\bfseries}p{1.4cm}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \caption[mnodels summary]{Summary results of the models}\label{tab:modelssummary}
  \begin{tabular}{
      C @{\hspace{1em}}
      *4{P{1.25cm}}
     @{\hspace{0.75em}}
      S[group-minimum-digits=4,table-format=4.1]
    }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Models Performance}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    \thead{Model}
      & \thead{Resid.\\Mean}
      & \thead{Const.\\Var.}
      & \thead{Auto\\corr.}
      & \thead{Adj.\\R\textsuperscript{2}}
      & {\thead{AIC}} \\ % {} required for S[] to work
    \midrule\midrule
    1 & OK & OK & YES & 0.83 &  4804.8 \\
    2 & OK & OK & YES & 0.84 &  4569.5 \\
    3 & OK & OK & YES & 0.83 &  4763.7 \\
    4 & OK & OK & YES & 0.87 &  3760.5 \\
    5 & OK & OK & YES & 0.86 &  3964.5 \\
    6 & No & No & YES & 0.32 & 10879.7 \\
    7 & No & No & YES & 0.80 &  5434.2 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```